# Parse saveAll vs individual saves in loop

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I was wondering if for a large number of updates (>1000) if **saveAll** or individual **save** in a loop should be used. For example, I am making a batch update to multiple objects in a class and both options work. What I am wondering about is whether for large number of updates, if there is limitations on how many objects **saveAll** can save accurately. I know that there was some limitation when this was running on free Parse.com account years ago, but I would think that limitation should no longer exist since Parse.com doesn't exist anymore.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a  50 objects limitation in one call (updates/saves). It depends a lot on the aftersave/beforesave cloud code. There is no time limit nor request limit. If your deploy is well orchestrated  you can push lots of items super fast. For example pm2 with multiple threads in a multicore cpu. You have also have in mind the mongodb hit. Normally it should be a issue saving is not as expensive as finding.

Comment: Thanks Arturo- can you point me towards documentation which shows the limitation? I wasn't able to find it on parse server guide..